# How do I increase percentage in SQL query / stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How do I increase percentage in SQL query / stored procedure?[closed] been answered!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

If you just want to select:

```
SELECT ename, esalary * 1.1 
  INTO name, salary 
    FROM employee 
 WHERE eno='113'
```

If you want to update

```
UPDATE employee
   SET salary =  salary * 1.1 
--If the base salary is store in esalary then use 
--SET salary = esalary * 1.1
 WHERE eno='113'
```

Comment: @Cybernate Do I do this after the first query?

Comment: In the select example you left out INTO?

Comment: If you want to update the data then run the second query... If you want to just display the salary with 10% increase run the first query....

Comment: Why do you need an into? If you want to simple update the data in the column just run the update unless you have to process the data after selecting...

Comment: If you looked at my initial code, I do process the data and put them in local variables!

Comment: Updated the post with the INTO clause.

Answer (score 1):

To `select`, try this:

```
select  name, salary * 1.1 from Employee where Eno='113';
```

to `update`

```
update employee set salary = salary * 1.1 where eno = '113'
```

Comment: The problem with your select statement is the into clause.